# Getting url with Intent Android

Tags: android, android-intent

Im trying to get the URL that was clicked in order to open the app.  Im just having trouble finding where I can get that information.  I have a manifest which opens app when clicked.  The link would be "http://host.com/file.html?param=1&param2=2" which Im trying to give to the app to handle.

```
 <intent-filter>
           <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="host.com" 
                android:pathPrefix="/file.html" />
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 </intent-filter>
```

EDIT

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Uri uri = intent.getData();
        try {
            url = new URL(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPath());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to get the intent data in your activity with the following:

```
Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
URL url = new URL(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPath());
```

Comment: I added my current OnCreate method up top. still isn't seeming to work though.

Comment: My onCreate Method seems to be not being called, from my understanding it will be called when the system calls onCreate and it will redirect to the onCreate I made by overriding it.

Answer (score 5):

Basically once you obtain your Uri (that is, `getIntent().getData()`), you can read your  complete url as `uri.toString()`. Assuming your `android:host` is valid and set, you can also get actual query data by calling `uri.getEncodedQuery()`.

Here is more details from working sample, if needed:

1. This is my manifest setup:

```
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="boo.acme.com"
                    android:scheme="http" />
            </intent-filter>
```

2. This is how I read  Uri:

```
Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
```

3. Assuming user clicked url "http://boo.acme.com/?ll=43.455095,44.177416", `uri.toString()` produces "http://boo.acme.com/?ll=43.455095,44.177416" and `uri.getEncodedQuery()` produces "ll=43.455095,44.177416".

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = this.getIntent().getData();
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(uri.getScheme(), uri.getHost(), uri.getPath());
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException e)
    {

    }
```

You will have to Surround with try/catch.